# How to set up i18n for node.js for multiple resource files of same language?

Tags: node.js, module, internationalization

I am trying to set up i18n for different json files of the the same language. The convention is every js file has a /locales/en.json in its folder. I have this so far

```
const i18n = require("i18n");
i18n.configure({
    locales: ["en"],
    directory: __dirname + "/locales"
});
```

This works for one file, but if I do this on another js file, this overrides the i18n with the json file of the most recent call, and the resource of the first one will be gone. I believe the trick is to load new instances of i18n, but this is a singelton with no api to make a new copy. I tried freshimport but it didn't work either.

Anyone know how to fix this?